# Problems in Wikipedia about symmetry group of the non-equilateral isosceles triangle.

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

I think this wikipedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group#Two_dimensions - is wrong when it states that "$D_2$, which is isomorphic to the Klein four-group, is the symmetry group of a non-equilateral isosceles triangle (...)", since the symmetry group of the non-equilateral isosceles triangle would be $D_1$, like the symmetry group of the letter ${\bf A}$ (order 2).

Also, this article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle - says that the symmetry group of the isoceles triangle is $D_2$ ($Dih_2$), and that this group has order $2$. But the order of a dihedral group $D_n$, as said in the previous article, is $2n$, so $D_2$ must have order 4, right?

Comment: That depends on the convention. Here they mean D_n to have order n.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the symmetry group of a non-equilateral isosceles triangle has order 2. And, depending on convention, $D_n$ either has order $n$ or $2n$.

Comment: ok, but the whole sentence doesn't make sense: "$D_1$ is the 2-element group containing the identity operation and a single reflection, which occurs when the figure has only a single axis of bilateral symmetry, for example the letter ${\bf A}$. $D_2$, which is isomorphic to the Klein four-group, is the symmetry group of a non-equilateral isosceles triangle (...)".

Comment: This two groups described seems to be the same.

Comment: I think there's no convex polygon whose symmetry group is isomorphic to the Klein four-group.

Comment: @Panini What about a rectangle?

Comment: @A.P. You're rigth. But the sentence is still wrong, right?

Comment: Yes, the sentence above is wrong, because a triangle cannot have a group of symmetry of order four. I see that Wikipedia has already been edited though. As far as I can tell, it is now correct, except for the fact that the two articles use different conventions for dihedral groups.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Notation) on dihedral groups, there are two different conventions in which the group denoted by $D_n$ can be either

- the dihedral group of *order* $n$, or
- the automorphism group of a regular polyhedron with $n$ sides (which has order $2n$).

**Update:** The above is addressing only the last (and only) question in your post's body. You are correct in pointing out that the symmetry group of a (non-equilateral) isosceles triangle isn't the Klein-four group, though.

**Update 2:** The Wikipedia article on symmetry groups has been fixed since you asked this question. An example of plane figure with the Klein-four as symmetry group is a non-equilateral rectangle. The four symmetries are: the identity, the reflections that swap the two pairs of opposite sides, and the rotation by $\pi$.

Comment: I fear we fell victim of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/217549), but hopefully my edit fully addressed your question.

Comment: A non-square rectangle has only four symmetries. (The reflections along the diagonals are not symmetries.)